# How to fix the correct html file as homepage?

Tags: apache-2.2, google, web-crawler, google-webmaster-tools

A search for my domain shows defaulthomepage along with html file that my hosting service, using plesk 9.5.4, provides as a placeholder. I have since deleted the old index file and added a new index.html file, but google result still shows this placeholder html.

Since I couldn't pin-point what is the problem, I have been trying out different methods over the past week:  redirecting in htacess to index.html, sending sitemap to google, getting google to fetch the new pages.

Appreciate if someone could direct me to the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. This question doesn't appear to be on topic here. You may wish to try our sister site [webmasters.se] instead, though you also may want to search there as your question may already have been answered.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Google is not a "live" search, at least not for the vast majority of sites that get indexed every few weeks or so. Just wait until the Googlebot visit your site again or [read this](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35843&topic=1724124&ctx=topic).